# Set notation, inclusion in a power set.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I'm reading through paper notes that have a lot of topology and set theory references.  I've ended up with a few questions that I cannot answer regarding nuance of a set $A$ when I read through the work.  My question is basically about format.  The first couple, are easy:

$A \in 2^A$, which is $A$ in $2^A$

$A \subset 2^A$, which is $A$ is contained in $2^A$

The part that gets me is when I get to notation of

$\{A\} \subset 2^A$ and $\{A,A\} \subset 2^A$.

In the first example,  $\{A\}$ is just the set of $A$, correct? Why is this not redundant?  What would $\{A,A\}$ be because the set of $A$ and $A$ are both included in the super set of $2^A$.  Is there some nuance to this notation?

Comment: $A$ is a set (of points, numbers, whatever). $\{ A \}$ is a set with only **one** element : $A$ itself.

Comment: I think your confusion may rest in the fact that while $A\in P(A)$, $\{A\}$ is a subset of $P(A)$.  (A itself is not a subset of the power set of A)

Comment: @amWhy I think you just answered my question.

Comment: IMO $\{A,A\}$ does not denote a set, as the elements mustn't be repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm transferring my comment to an answer:

I'll use $\mathcal P(A)$ instead of the equivalent $2^A$.

I think your confusion may rest in the fact that while $A \in \mathcal P(A)$,

$\{A\}$ is a *subset* of $\mathcal P(A)$.

(Note that $A$ itself is *not a subset* of of $\mathcal P(A)$.

For example: suppose $A =\{0, 1\}$.  Then $$\mathcal P(A) = \{\varnothing, \{0\}, \{1\}, \{0, 1\}\}$$

Clearly $A = \{0, 1\} \in \mathcal P(A),\;\;$  while $\;\{A\} = \{\{0, 1\}\} \subset \mathcal P(A)$

Comment: Note also that $\{A, A\} = \{A\}$.